# Do hidden form elements get submitted?

Tags: jquery, forms

If jQuery's `toggle()` is used on a `<div>` containing form elements, will those form elements get submitted with the form, even though they are hidden?

My code (though probably not needed for this particular question):

```
$('.cms_loop_title').click(function(){
    $ctg = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.'+$ctg).toggle();
    //alert($ctg);
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to prevent submitting, you have to disable the elements. Hiding doesn't do the trick (I had the same issue a while ago)

Answer (score 24):

Yes, they'll get submitted unless they are removed from the document or have the `disabled` attribute set on them.

For more information, see the HTML5 Working Draft — [Section 4.10.22.4 Constructing the form data set](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constructing-form-data-set).  The information there is more-or-less the same as previous HTML versions.

Comment: Removing them from the DOM will also prevent them from being submitted, but toggle just hides them with CSS.