# How to assign 0 to hidden data and perform the reverse on slider control?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql

So I'm trying assign 0 to some hidden dynamic text boxes, and the post the visible input data in the next page. The hiding and showing of these text boxes is controlled by a slider that is above those text fields. I would also like to perform the reverse of this when the data is shown again.

```
<!-- MASTER TEXT FIELD WHERE DATA ENTERED IS REFLECTED IN ALL TEXT FIELDS 
CREATED IN THE LOOP --> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="add0" id="add0" 
onkeyup="sync()">
<!-- END -->

<form action="add.php" method="GET">
<div class="row">
$counter = 1;
while ($res = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

<!-- THIS ENTIRE DIV GETS SHOWN/HID WHEN THE SLIDER IS MOVED -->
<div class="col-md-2 show-hide">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $res['size']; ?> " name="size[]" id= " 
<?php echo $res['size']; ?>" readonly style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
class="form-control" />

<!-- DYNAMIC TEXT FIELDS ARE DISPLAYED HERE -->
<div id="addition<?php echo $counter; ?>"> 
</div>
</div>
<!-- END OF DIV THAT GETS SHOWN/HID -->

<?php
$counter = $counter + 1;}
</div>
<button type="submit" value="submit">Apply</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
<!-- CODE TO ASSIGN DYNAMIC ID'S TO INPUT FIELDS -->
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++)     
{
$('#addition' + i).append('<input class="form-control" type="text" 
name="add[]" id="add' + i + '" />');
}
}       
</script>

<!-- CODE FOR SLIDER -- >
$('#slider').slider({
min: 36,
max: 50,
step: 1,
values: [36, 50],
range: true,
slide: function (event, ui) {
$.each(ui.values, function (i, v) {
$('input.value').eq(i).val(v);
});

<!-- SCRIPT TO HIDE AND SHOW DATA -->
$('.show-hide').each(function (idx, div) {
var $div = $(div);
var value = $div.children().first().val();
if (value < ui.values[0] || value > ui.values[1]) {

<!-- TO ASSIGN 0 WHEN THE FIELDS -->
$div.find('input:nth-of-type(2)').val('0');
$div.hide();
} 
else {
<!-- THE FIELD IS CLEARED-->
$div.find('input:nth-of-type(2)').val('');
$div.show();
}});
}});
<!-- END OF HIDE/SHOW SCRIPT -->  

$('input.value').change(function () {
var $this = $(this);
$('#slider').slider('values', $this.attr('data-index'), 
$this.val());
});
<!-- END CODE FOR SLIDER --> 
 });
```

The slider is working fine here, but the problem is that even after hiding and submitting the form, 0 is not getting assigned to the hidden fields and the data entered in the master textbox is getting reflected in it and getting submitted to the next page
The expected output is the hidden text field will be assigned zero, and will do the complete opposite when it's shown again.

This is how it looks like.
https://ibb.co/t4TcV4S

Comment: [Hidden elements still get submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794921/do-hidden-form-elements-get-submitted)

Comment: Hi James. I have updated the post. It's okay if the hidden element gets submitted, but I just want the hidden fields to be assigned 0 and clear the zero when it' shown again.

Comment: Hidden fields by css (display none or inside element which has display none)? Because as you maybe know, input fields are not send if they are not displayed by css rule display: none.... use instead visibility:hidden and position:absolute

Comment: No they are getting hidden. But since the textboxes are dynamic, I feel like the problem is with $div.find('input:nth-of-type(2)').val('0');

Comment: From your last sentence *The expected output...*, it sounds like you want fields that you "hide" to not get submitted to add.php.  If that is not your problem/requirement, can you clarify please.

Comment: I actually want the hidden fields to be assigned 0 and the field must be blank when it's shown again. The values will be submitted either way.